# thymleaf th:id value in javascript

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Need to check format of the value of a textfield inside the Javascript.

I am using thymeleaf for rendering the page.

To achieve this I plan to use th:id and use this inside Javascript (similar to document.getElementById and read the value. But I donot know how to get the value of the textfield inside the javascript as I am doing an iteration..

Below is the scenario

While iterating through a Map<String,Field> (where Field is a class containing two elements fieldValueList (List) and timeField(boolean) check for the format of the textField entered in the page, (format of the textfield should be hh:mm:ss) need to be done in javascript. I used id for reading the value, but donot know how to get the value of the textfield inside the javascript.

The code for the page is

```
<fieldSet th:each="fieldKey,fieldKeyIndex : *{recipeFieldMap.keySet()}">
    <div class="fieldDiv" th:each="fieldVal,field : *{recipeFieldMap[__${fieldKey}__].fieldValueList}">
        <span class="fieldSpan" th:if="*{recipeFieldMap[__${fieldKey}__].timeField}">
            <input type="text" th:id="|text_${fieldKeyIndex.index}_${field.index}|" th:field="*{recipeFieldMap[__${fieldKey}__].fieldTimeValueList[__${field.index}__].displayStr}" onchange="checkTimeStr()">
            <script th:inline="javascript">
                /*<![CDATA[*/
                function checkTimeStr() {
                    // Something like this.. to read the value
                    //var value = document.getElementById('/* text_${groupKeyIndex.index}_${field.index} */').value;
                    //alert(value)
                }
                /*]]>*/
            </script>
        </span>
        <span class="fieldSpan" th:unless="*{recipeFieldMap[__${fieldKey}__].timeField}">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{recipeFieldMap[__${fieldKey}__].fieldValueList[__${field.index}__]}">
        </span>
    </div>
</fieldSet>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoAF4.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    [[${field.index}]]
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Amir, I think my framing of the question was wrong. Therfore I had edited my Post again. 

By using your suggestion I always get the highest index of the list(num_of_elements - 1). 

My main issue is  to read the textdata entered by the user and check this data. Since it is in list I am facing issues to read this textField.

I had also added an image in the post now for more information. There you can find that the expected format of the field is hh:mm:ss. I would like to check this in the javascript.